# ActiveRecord save in after_save callback not persisting during rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working on a foosball logging application.

My models follow the scheme:
Game -> Team -> Position -> Goal

In Goal I have an after_save that will check if either team has scored 10 goals. If a team has, then it sets a winner(Team) and sets the Game.completed_at.

This functionality seems to save the winner and Game.completed_at in practice through user testing, but in my Rspec tests after a team reaches 10 goals I see the after_save callback being called in Goal, but after the callback in the test its as if none of those columns were saved. I'm not exactly sure what is going on.

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :complete_game
    def complete_game

      game = self.position.team.game
      isGameComplete = false

      game.teams.each do |team|
        if team.get_goals_total == 10
            team.winner = true
            team.save!
            puts "complete_game: team.winner: #{team.winner}"

            game.completed_at = DateTime.now
            game.save!

            isGameComplete = true
      end
    end
    puts "complete_game: game.completed_at: #{game.completed_at}"
  end
```

Rspec Test:

```
it "sets a winner after ten goals" do 
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create

  puts "winner: #{@blue_team.winner}"
  puts "completed_at: '#{@game.completed_at}'"

  expect(@blue_team.winner).to be true
end
```

Rspec Output:

```
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: game.completed_at:
complete_game: team.winner: true
complete_game: game.completed_at: 02/20/2015 12:44 PM
TEST OUTPUT: winner: false
TEST OUTPUT: completed_at: ''
    sets a winner after ten goals (FAILED - 1)
```

Looking at the logs the after_save sets the winner/completed_at, but outside of the callback in 'TEST OUTPUT' then winner/completed_at are not set.

Do callbacks in rspec tests not persist changes made in after_save callbacks? Works in production, doesn't seem to save changes in testing.

Answer (score 2):

Received the following answer asking the question on reddit.com/r/rails (http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/2wlhrf/how_to_testing_before_save_callbacks/)

After the callback was performed on the Team model, a **.reload** of the corresponding object was required.

Test passed as expected.

```
it "sets a winner after ten goals" do

  10.times do
    @blue_team.positions.first.goals.create
  end

  expect(@blue_team.reload.winner).to be true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `stub` callback actions :

```
@blue_team.stub(:complete_game).and_return(true)
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the rspec documentation that supports your claim?